# Proximity Search

Tags: 7, search, location

So i'm trying to set up an online store kinda thing. The user uploads items and others see it in their news feed. I want items listed based on the location proximity of the user.

Say there are 3 people accessing the news feed. The item closest to that person should come up first in the news feed.

I'm getting the location of the user during registration and i want this location to get attached with the item.

Answer (score 0):

I once put together a similar system for users physically near each other to find and contact each other, but the best way I ever came up with was to store every distance in the database.

Essentially, I saved the lat/lon location (via the Google Maps API) of each user when they registered. Then (via cron) I calculated that user's distance from every other user and saved that distance in a custom table. That allowed me to simply query the database sorting by shortest distance.

This requires a substantial amount of overhead, depending on the number of users (and items, in your case), but it worked reasonably well.

I know that some databases have custom geo data types now, that allow this kind of query automatically, but that's somewhat outside the realm of Drupal.